# TortoiseSVN - doesn't work for Vista 64 user other than installer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN works fine on Vista 64 bit for the user account who installed it.  When I login as a different user, TortoiseSVN is not there.  I tried running file explorer as administrator.  It seems that TortoiseSVN only attaches to explorer for the user who installed it.

How do I get TortoiseSVN to work for users other than the installer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worded my question badly.  It works for other accounts - the context menu shows and works, but the icon overlays were not showing.  I realized I set the dot net hack variable for the administrator account only.  Once I moved the settings to apply to everyone else, the icons came back for the non admin user.  I know that I really don't need the hack for vs 2008 - I'll eventually turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't there a step during installation when it asked you whether or not to install for all users?